# What is causing these functions to loop faster than once per second?

Tags: javascript

When the original key expires, subsequent keys are generated immediately instead of waiting for new keys to expire.
[cycling through keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPD3N.gif)

```
async function getActivationToken() {
        let json = await fetch(`/api/user/activate`, {headers: {"Authorization": token}}).then(response=>response.json());
        setActivationText(json);
    }
    
    function setActivationText(json) {
        let timeleft = json.data.expires - Math.trunc(Date.now()/1000);
        let activationtext = document.getElementById("activation-key");
        if(timeleft < 1) {
            activationtext.innerHTML = `<h1 class="text-xl">Your activation key is: <span class="text-green-500">Loading...</span></h1><h1 class="text-xl">This key will expire in <span class="text-green-500">Loading...</span></h1>`
            return getActivationToken();
        } 
        else {
            activationtext.innerHTML = `<h1 class="text-xl">Your activation key is: <span class="text-green-500">${json.data.activation}</span></h1><h1 class="text-xl">This key will expire <span class="text-green-500">in ${secondsToMinutesAndSeconds(timeleft)}</span></h1>`;
            return setInterval(setActivationText, 1000, json);
        }
        
    }
    getActivationToken();
```

I tried setting a timeout on the getActivationToken() function, but that just added a second to the wait time after the first key was generated and resulted in the same problem.

```
async function getActivationToken() {
        let json = await fetch(`/api/user/activate`, {headers: {"Authorization": token}}).then(response=>response.json());
        setTimeout(setActivationText, 1000, json);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating more and more time interval when `timeleft` greater than `1`.
in else statement in `setActivationText`, it should be `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.